# Insert null instead of 0 in the database for an integer

Tags: database, hibernate, null

I'm using hibernate And I have a class Structure that contains an id, name And a structure object

Structure(ID,NAME,Structure) The default value of the id is 0 because it is an integer.

This object can contain a parent object of the same type or not.

So at the time of inserting if parent object is null I want to have id of the parent object in the null database and not 0.

Here is my modele

```
@Entity
public class Structure implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long idt_structure;
private String name;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="idt_parent_structure")
private Structure structure;

// Getters and setters
}
```

And here is the function for insertion

```
    public void save(){
    if(this.idt_structure != null){
        Structure structureParent = (Structure) structureService.findStructureById(idt_structure);
        structure.setStructure(structureParent);    
    }
    else{
        structure.setStructure(structure);
    }
    structureService.addStructure(structure);
    structures=structureService.listStructures();
}
```

Comment: Your post is hard to understand, please edit to clarify. Eg do you mean to ask, if the object is Java null in the Java program then how do I make the structure field be SQL null in the database? And please add an example of input & output.